# looping through url

Tags: php, loops

I want to do a loop, normally it is done with `while` `do` `for` etc but when the process is big I came up with a solution to refresh the page by echoing a javascript to refresh the page for the next loop.

for example:

The page is `http://localhost/index.php` --> this preforms the first iteration with `$i=1;`

at the end of the script it will be redirected to `http://localhost/index.php?i=$i++`

```
if (!$_GET['i']){
 $i = 1;
}else{
 $i = $_GET['i'];
}
if ($i<500){
 // proceed with $i = $_GET['i']
 //then redirect to  http://localhost/index.php?i=$i++
}else{
 echo "done";
}
```

Now, consider a situation that the imput parameters come from a FORM to this script. (i.e. `$parameter1 , $parameter2, $parameter3`)
Then I have to pass them every time to new url (next iteration).

At normal work I can pass them as GET variable to new url but how can I pass them if I don't want the user be able to see the value of parameters in url?

Answer (score 1):

> At normal work I can pass them as GET variable to new url but how can I pass them if I don't want the user be able to see the value of parameters in url?

You can not with the bare redirect, but if you're talking about a specific user, you can do so by assigning those parameters as [session variables <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php) and then passing the session id as an additional parameter (or trust the user has cookies enabled).

```
function do_redirect($i, Array $parameters)
{
   $i = (int) $i;
   $parameters['i'] = $i; // save to session as well
   $_SESSION['parameters'] = $parameters;
   // redirect to http://localhost/index.php?i=$i&SID
}

if (is_form_request())
{
    $parameters = get_form_parameters();
    do_redirect(1, $parameters);
}
elseif (is_redirect_loop_request())
{
    $parameters = $_SESSION['parameters'];
    $i = $parameters['i'];
    if ($i < 500)
    {
        do_redirect($i++, $parameters);
    } else {
        echo "done.";
    }
}
```

Comment: user can read the cookies, I do that often. I don't want them to be readable. would I encode the values with key? base64_encode with key is possible?

Comment: Parameters are not stored inside the cookie with sessions. Parameters are kept server side.

Comment: You could even regenerate the session id per each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be rude, but both answers above are quite prone to security issues (but the session solution is the best one). As for the 'encryption' solution of @itamar: that's not exactly encryption... This is called 'Caesar cypher' (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher), which is indeed as safe as a paper nuclear bunker...

It can be much easier and safe as can be; do not save the iteration in the session, but in the database. For the next request, the only thing you have to do is get the iterator from the database and go on with whatever you want to do. Sessions can be stolen, meaning someone could let you iterate from, say, $i=10 a thousand times. It cannot be done when the iterator is stored in a secure database.